# Getting exception when I try to populate data from a gridview to the text boxes

Tags: c#, frameworks

The exception I get:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the 
>   collection. Parameter name: index

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        LoadData();
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            var rowId = Convert.ToChar(e.CommandArgument);
            var hf = (HiddenField)((GridView)e.CommandSource).Rows[rowId].FindControl("hfKey");
            var AccountNo = String.Format(hf.Value);
```